# Transformations between two coordinate systems on a rigid body

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, transformation, coordinate-systems

I have two coordinate frames, A and B, which are rigidly attached to each other on a body. This body then translates and rotates, such that A starts at A<sub>1</sub>, and moves to A<sub>2</sub>, and B starts at B<sub>1</sub>, and moves to B<sub>2</sub>. This is shown in the diagram below.

[image]

By inspection of the grid, I have calculated the transformation matrix (in 3D homogeneous coordinates) from A<sub>1</sub> to B<sub>1</sub> to be as follows:

$$ T_{A_1B_1} = \left [\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 & 0 & -2 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array} \right ]$$

Then after the movement, again by inspection of the grid, I have calculated the transformation matrix (in 3D homogeneous coordinates) from A<sub>2</sub> to B<sub>2</sub> to be as follows:

$$ T_{A_2B_2} = \left [\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array} \right ]$$

Why are these matrices not the same? Have I calculated them incorrectly? Or is my diagram inconsistent somehow?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if I had to transform $A1$ to $A2$ by a rotation and then a translation I would do it with homogeneous coordinates and in 4 steps (4 matrices).

- 1) $T_1$: translate $A1$ to the origin (down 4 and left 1)
- 2) $T_2$: do the rotation (90 degrees clockwise)
- 3) $T_3$: translate back (up 4 and right 1)
- 4) $T_4$: translate right 3 and down 1.

  $$T=T_4T_3T_2T_1= \begin{bmatrix} 
  1&0&3\\
  0&1&-1\\
  0&0&1\\
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix} 
  1&0&1\\
  0&1&4\\
  0&0&1\\
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix} 
  0&1&0\\
  -1&0&0\\
  0&0&1\\
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix} 
  1&0&-1\\
  0&1&-4\\
  0&0&1\\
  \end{bmatrix}$$

Which gives the full transformation from $A1$ to $A2$

$$ 
T=\begin{bmatrix} 
0&1&0\\
-1&0&4\\
0&0&1\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

The reason this **does not** work on $B1$ is because of the rotation. $B1$ is not centered about the origin when $A1$ is. You need to make sure the rotation (or reflection) works for both $A1$ and $B1$ at the same time.